# My simple Android app does not show options menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a simple app using AndEngine in Android. I'm trying to add options menu, but for some reasons it does not show up. Surprisingly, the options menu button is not even shown! (the 3-dots touch button on bottom right of page). What's wrong?

**EDIT:** I already have `menu.xml`. Still it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is the piece of code corresponding to the `MenuScene` (AndEngine's example code **[here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextMenuExample.java)**)

```
    public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnMenuItemClickListener {
        private static int CAMERA_WIDTH ;
        private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT;

        protected static final int MENU_ADD = 0;
        protected static final int MENU_QUIT = MENU_ADD + 1;



        private Font mFont,menuFont;
        private MenuScene mMenuScene;
        Camera camera;
        Scene scene;

        @Override
        public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
//default code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateResources() throws IOException {
//some code
        }

        @Override
        public Scene onCreateScene() {
 //some code
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClicked(final MenuScene pMenuScene, final IMenuItem pMenuItem, final float pMenuItemLocalX, final float pMenuItemLocalY) {
            switch(pMenuItem.getID()) {
            case MENU_ADD:
                /* Restart the animation. */
                Log.i("hello", "Menu ADD CLICKED");
                return true;

            case MENU_QUIT:
                /* End Activity. */
                this.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected MenuScene createMenuScene() {
            final MenuScene menuScene = new MenuScene(this.camera, new AlphaMenuSceneAnimator());

            final IMenuItem resetMenuItem = new ColorMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(MENU_ADD, this.menuFont, "ADD ITEM", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()), new Color(1,0,0), new Color(0,0,0));
            menuScene.addMenuItem(resetMenuItem);
            final IMenuItem quitMenuItem = new ColorMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(MENU_QUIT, this.menuFont, "QUIT", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()), new Color(1,0,0), new Color(0,0,0));

            menuScene.addMenuItem(quitMenuItem);
            menuScene.buildAnimations();
            menuScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
            menuScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            return menuScene;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(final int pKeyCode, final KeyEvent pEvent) {
            if(pKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && pEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(this.scene.hasChildScene()) {
                    /* Remove the menu and reset it. */
                    this.mMenuScene.back();
                } else {
                    /* Attach the menu. */
                    this.scene.setChildScene(this.mMenuScene, false, true, true);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onKeyDown(pKeyCode, pEvent);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Add the code in `menu.xml` file. It is in `res` folder of your project.

Comment: @SamratDutta Well, the original AndEngine example project does not even have menu.xml file, but it works there! I have it in my project. What code should I enter there?

Comment: Yeah, I checked. You do not the code in menu.xml, because the menu items are generated dynamically. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @SamratDutta any news?

Comment: Nopes. I read about this AndEngine and dynamically generating menus. Went through all the examples. Still cant seem to find any error in your code. Perhaps @Commonsware can answer your question when he comes online. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `menu.xml` in the `res/menu` folder. This file will contain the list of items for the list in the following format:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

You also need to inflate the menu from your activity just like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @tina_jasmin are you inflating it with the onCreateOptionsMenu method? Does it have items? Are you using an ActionBarActivity? Día you look in the examples of andengine were it inflates the menu?

Comment: I'm simply following the source code for AndEngine's example code here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextMenuExample.java